# Last date in quarter MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with some dates. I need a query which will return the max (last) date from this table and last date of quarter this max date belongs to.

So for data i table

```
ID|  EDATE
--+----------
 1|2014-03-06
 2|2014-10-12
```

this query should return 2014-10-12 and 2014-12-31.

Comment: Do you use MySQL from another language like PHP or just from the command line?

Comment: is the table date a date field or a varchar?

Comment: I use PHP as my programming language but it doesn't matter now since I need pure SQL query which will return two wanted dates. EDATE column is DATE type column (not VARCHAR).

Comment: Have you considered using a date dimension table to be able to relate individual dates to things like quarters?

Comment: I don't get the idea of returning the `end of quarter` based on a date, as your expected result `2014-10-12` is not the end of a quarter.

Comment: I need last date from table, this is 2014-10-12, then I need the last date of quarter in which is this 2014-10-12 (this is 4th quarter and it's last date of this quarter is 2014-12-31).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the simplest answer:

```
SELECT MAKEDATE(YEAR(edate),1)
       + INTERVAL QUARTER(edate) QUARTER
       - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

This query takes the first day of year, adds quarters to it and subtracts 1 day to get the last day in wanted quarter. So the required query should look like:

```
SELECT MAX(edate),
       MAKEDATE(YEAR(MAX(edate)),1)
       + INTERVAL QUARTER(MAX(edate)) QUARTER
       - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want the last day of the quarter, so 31 March, 30 June, 30 Sept, 31 Dec? So you can use the answer from Gordon Linoff and adjust it to do that.

You only need a case statement on month(date) and concat that with the year.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/control-flow-functions.html

```
str_to_date(
    concat(
        year(edate),
        (case
            when month(edate) in (1, 2, 3) then '-03-31'
            when month(edate) in (4, 5, 6) then '-06-30'
            when month(edate) in (7, 8, 9) then '-09-30'
            else '-12-31'
        end)
    ),
    '%Y-%m-%d'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the day of the last quarter for the date is a bit yucky, but possible.  Here is a sort of brute force solution:

```
select edate,
       str_to_date(concat(year(edate), '-', 1 + floor((month(edate) - 1)/ 3)) * 3, '-',
                          (case when month(edate) in (1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12) then 31 else 30 end)),
                   '%Y-%m-%d'
                  )
from table t
order by edate desc
limit 1;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/43537) is a SQL Fiddle that demonstrates it.

Comment: I don't think this is right. What about February with only 28 days

Comment: @Jay . . . Why would that pose a problem?  This is only using the month and year portions of the date.  Run the SQL Fiddle, change the date, and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LAST_DAY` to select the last day of a specific month depending on where your quarters end you may have to change the `3,6,9,12` to different months.

```
select t1.max_date,
(
  case 
  when month(max_date) <= 3
  then last_day(concat(year(max_date),'-3-1'))  
  when month(max_date) <= 6
  then last_day(concat(year(max_date),'-6-1'))
  when month(max_date) <= 9
  then last_day(concat(year(max_date),'-9-1'))
  else last_day(concat(year(max_date),'-12-1'))
  end
) last_quarter_day
from (
    select max(EDATE) max_date from myTable
) t1
```